# installing broadcom 802.11 driver problems

Tags: 16.04, drivers, broadcom

I have a very poor signal with unstable connection on my BCM43142 wireless adapter. when I installed ubuntu for first time I had `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver by default installed and I chose it in software&update window which gives poor signal and low speed. 
I also was able to install `wireless-bcm43421-oneiric-dkms` by a `.deb` file but not uninstall the previous one and that is still in the list of additional drivers, I did unselect that and chose `wireless-bcm43421-oneiric-dkms` after reboot there is no WiFi option to enable.
now I decided to install `broadcom-sta-6.30`. in the requirements README file of the package it says; On Ubuntu, you will need headers and tools.  Try these commands:

```
# sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
# sudo apt-get build-dep linux
```

but on `build-dep` Is receive :

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for linux
```

also after that the Build instruction is complicated to me as I am new to Linux and Ubuntu
what should I do with the Error first, has anyone had the same problem as me with the WiFi adapter ?
what is the best driver for BCM43142 [14e4:4365]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the source code repos activated in your sources.list. You can do that in the software and updates app, or manually edit it by doing `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` and uncommenting the lines by removing the # signs. They start with deb-src.

Also, you should run this command to get the headers to avoid pulling in unneeded stuff:`sudo apt-get build-dep --no-install-recommends linux`